# compound layout doesn't show inner views

Tags: android

I extended from LinearLayout and inflated views, but on the screen those views in my layout are not appeared. I see my view group in editor, but it seems like it's empty. No views inside it.

FragmentPickerViewGroup looks like this:

```
package com.test.pecode.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class FragmentPickerViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
   private ImageView background;
   private Button minusButton;
   private Button plusButton;

    public FragmentPickerViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_fragment_picker, this);
        minusButton = findViewById(R.id.minus_btn);
        plusButton = findViewById(R.id.plus_btn);
        background = findViewById(R.id.background_rectangle);

        minusButton.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        minusButton.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START);
        minusButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.button_bg);

        background.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.rectangle);
        background.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.rectangle);

        plusButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.button_bg);
        plusButton.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END);
   }

   public FragmentPickerViewGroup(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet 
    attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
   }

     public FragmentPickerViewGroup(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet 
        attrs, 
        int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
   }

     public FragmentPickerViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
        defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
   }
}
```

I used merge tag for my layout. Probably something goes wrong there? This is my layout, which I inflate into my view group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_rectangle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background_rectangle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</merge>
```

Comment: The issue was the following: I forgot to pass attributes into my `init()` method in custom view. So, that's why all my attributes didn't affected on layout.